# Laravel pass GET parameters from register form to custom redirect URL

Tags: laravel

When a user signs up they land on the register page with some GET parameters. After they register I'd like to redirect them to the next page and keep these GET parameters.

In `Auth\RegisterController` I think I can use the method `redirectTo` as defined in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers` trait.

But how can I achieve what I like using this method? Do I call it at the end of the `create()` method in the `RegisterController` like:

```
create()
{
  // ...
  $this-> redirectTo($request->get('param1'), $request->get('param2'))
}
```

and then define

```
protected function redirectTo($param1, $param2)
{
  return redirect()->route('example?param1='.$param1.'&param2='.$param2);
}
```

I'm not sure where `redirectTo()` should go and if this is the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use the routes and then play on the status of the application with the session.

Or you can modify the value of `$this->redirectTo` in the authenticated which gives you in parameter an instance of Request and the registered user.

```php
    /**
     * Register listener
     *
     * @param Reauest $request
     * @param User $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        $param1 = $request->get('param1');
        $param2 = $request->get('param2');

        $user->sendWelcomeNotification();

        $this->redirectTo = 'example?param1='.$param1.'&param2='.$param2;
    }
```